# A log of when the machine and/or monitor was turned on?

Tags: logs

Does GNU/Linux keep a log of when the machine and/or monitor was turned on?

I wish to limit my screen time by telling the machine to automatically hibernate 90 minutes after the last startup *or awake*. This precludes using `@reboot`, I think, and I don't think `cron` has an `@awake` parameter. Currently, `systemctrl suspend` runs every X minutes, even when the current session is is less than 90 minutes.

Comment: Is there a reason the task can not be a part of system startup or user login scripts? System startup and sleep/wakeup events tend to be logged in the system's logs (use `journalctl` on systemd systems or check `/var/log/` to read the logs).

Comment: User login might be a partial solution, but I don't want the script to reset because I locked it or because the monitor went to sleep. The ideal is to track uptime / time since last awake or start. `@reboot` won't work for reasons stated above. I have looked `journalctl` and `/var/log`, but there's a lot there. Can you specify?

Comment: may be related https://askubuntu.com/q/68918/10473

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/157037), I have an alternate solution.

For the machine startup. You can run a start up script, and use a sleep to delay the rest of the script.

You can probably do similar by attaching and script to an event for monitor on.

---

Edit following OP adding reason.

I think there are programs to help you limit screen time. I added a link to a related question to comments.

Comment: Thanks. I am still holding out hope that the I can do this in a one-line script, based on information from a log.